# How to get pixels out of a NodeSocketImage class using the blender python API

Tags: python, blender

I'm currently trying to program a custom compositor node in Python to transform an image to use the colors available in another image.

I have this code so far:

```
import bpy
import mathutils
from bpy.types import CompositorNode
from bpy.props import FloatProperty

class RemapNode(CompositorNode):
    bl_idname = 'REMAP_NODE'
    bl_label = 'Remap'
    bl_icon = 'NODE'

    def init(self, context):
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', 'Input')
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketImage', 'Palette')
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat', 'Dithering Factor')
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketImage', 'Output')

    def update(self):
        image_input = self.inputs['Input']
        image_map = self.inputs['Palette']

        input_data = image_input.default_value
        map_data = image_map.default_value
        if not input_data or not map_data:
            return
```

It seems to show as expected.

[image: Remap node]

However, I cannot get the pixels out of the NodeSocketImage. I've looked at the documentation and I'm a bit clueless on how to do this. I've also asked ChatGPT but it kept hallucinating solutions...

Do anyone have code examples for custom compositor nodes in Python? Thanks.